# Saving data using fragments

Tags: android, mysql, android-fragments

I want to know how can I save data into my custom MySQL database from my android app using fragments, I have called the function in oncreateview for saving data, but It  gives me error of Binary XML file error inflating class fragments and plenty other errors, please give me idea where i called the function for save the data with fragments,
 I am pasting some part of code as code was too lengthy

Below is my code:

```
public class ContactsListFragment extends ListFragment implements
            AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

        // Defines a tag for identifying log entries
        private static final String TAG = "ContactsListFragment";

        // Bundle key for saving previously selected search result item
        private static final String STATE_PREVIOUSLY_SELECTED_KEY =
                "com.example.android.contactslist.ui.SELECTED_ITEM";

        private static final Cursor Cursor = null;
         public    DBHandler db;

        private ContactsAdapter mAdapter; // The main query adapter
        private ImageLoader mImageLoader; // Handles loading the contact image in a background thread
        private String mSearchTerm; // Stores the current search query term

        // Contact selected listener that allows the activity holding this fragment to be notified of
        // a contact being selected
        private OnContactsInteractionListener mOnContactSelectedListener;

        // Stores the previously selected search item so that on a configuration change the same item
        // can be reselected again
        private int mPreviouslySelectedSearchItem = 0;

        // Whether or not the search query has changed since the last time the loader was refreshed
        private boolean mSearchQueryChanged;

        // Whether or not this fragment is showing in a two-pane layout
        private boolean mIsTwoPaneLayout;

        // Whether or not this is a search result view of this fragment, only used on pre-honeycomb
        // OS versions as search results are shown in-line via Action Bar search from honeycomb onward
        private boolean mIsSearchResultView = false;

        /**
         * Fragments require an empty constructor.
         */
        public ContactsListFragment() {}

        /**
         * In platform versions prior to Android 3.0, the ActionBar and SearchView are not supported,
         * and the UI gets the search string from an EditText. However, the fragment doesn't allow
         * another search when search results are already showing. This would confuse the user, because
         * the resulting search would re-query the Contacts Provider instead of searching the listed
         * results. This method sets the search query and also a boolean that tracks if this Fragment
         * should be displayed as a search result view or not.
         *
         * @param query The contacts search query.
         */
        public void setSearchQuery(String query) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(query)) {
                mIsSearchResultView = false;
            } else {
                mSearchTerm = query;
                mIsSearchResultView = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Check if this fragment is part of a two-pane set up or a single pane by reading a
            // boolean from the application resource directories. This lets allows us to easily specify
            // which screen sizes should use a two-pane layout by setting this boolean in the
            // corresponding resource size-qualified directory.
            mIsTwoPaneLayout = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.has_two_panes);

            // Let this fragment contribute menu items
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            Log.d("Hope","Hope 3");

            // Create the main contacts adapter
            mAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(getActivity());

            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                // If we're restoring state after this fragment was recreated then
                // retrieve previous search term and previously selected search
                // result.
                mSearchTerm = savedInstanceState.getString(SearchManager.QUERY);
                mPreviouslySelectedSearchItem =
                        savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_PREVIOUSLY_SELECTED_KEY, 0);
            }

            /*
             * An ImageLoader object loads and resizes an image in the background and binds it to the
             * QuickContactBadge in each item layout of the ListView. ImageLoader implements memory
             * caching for each image, which substantially improves refreshes of the ListView as the
             * user scrolls through it.
             *
             * To learn more about downloading images asynchronously and caching the results, read the
             * Android training class Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently.
             *
             * http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/
             */
            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(getActivity(), getListPreferredItemHeight()) {
                @Override
                protected Bitmap processBitmap(Object data) {
                    // This gets called in a background thread and passed the data from
                    // ImageLoader.loadImage().
                    return loadContactPhotoThumbnail((String) data, getImageSize());
                }
            };

            // Set a placeholder loading image for the image loader
            mImageLoader.setLoadingImage(R.drawable.ic_contact_picture_holo_light);

            // Add a cache to the image loader
            mImageLoader.addImageCache(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), 0.1f);
        }
```

This is oncreateView function where I tend to save the all the contact into my custom mysql database,

> This is the point I had a error of error inflating class fragmentns.

```
   **@Override
```

*>     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,

> ```
>               Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>           // Inflate the list fragment layout
>            SavingContacts savingcontacts=new SavingContacts();
>            final String photoUri = Cursor.getString(ContactsQuery.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_DATA);
>                final String ContactID = Cursor.getString(ContactsQuery.ID);
>                final String Lookup = Cursor.getString(ContactsQuery.LOOKUP_KEY);
>                final String displayName = Cursor.getString(ContactsQuery.DISPLAY_NAME);
>           //   SavingContacts savingcontacts=new SavingContacts();
>            savingcontacts.savingcontact(ContactID, displayName, photoUri, Lookup);
>           return inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_list_fragment, container, false);
>       }***
> ```

And this contact query interface, in this contactlistfragment

```
public interface ContactsQuery {

            // An identifier for the loader
            final static int QUERY_ID = 1;

            // A content URI for the Contacts table
            final static Uri CONTENT_URI = Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

            // The search/filter query Uri
            final static Uri FILTER_URI = Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI;
            public  void savedata(Cursor cursor);

            // The selection clause for the CursorLoader query. The search criteria defined here
            // restrict results to contacts that have a display name and are linked to visible groups.
            // Notice that the search on the string provided by the user is implemented by appending
            // the search string to CONTENT_FILTER_URI.
            @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
            final static String SELECTION =
                    (Utils.hasHoneycomb() ? Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY : Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME) +
                    "<>''" + " AND " + Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + "=1";

            // The desired sort order for the returned Cursor. In Android 3.0 and later, the primary
            // sort key allows for localization. In earlier versions. use the display name as the sort
            // key.
            @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
            final static String SORT_ORDER =
                    Utils.hasHoneycomb() ? Contacts.SORT_KEY_PRIMARY : Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;

            // The projection for the CursorLoader query. This is a list of columns that the Contacts
            // Provider should return in the Cursor.
            @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
            final static String[] PROJECTION = {

                    // The contact's row id
                    Contacts._ID,

                    // A pointer to the contact that is guaranteed to be more permanent than _ID. Given
                    // a contact's current _ID value and LOOKUP_KEY, the Contacts Provider can generate
                    // a "permanent" contact URI.
                    Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,

                    // In platform version 3.0 and later, the Contacts table contains
                    // DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY, which either contains the contact's displayable name or
                    // some other useful identifier such as an email address. This column isn't
                    // available in earlier versions of Android, so you must use Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
                    // instead.
                    Utils.hasHoneycomb() ? Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY : Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,

                    // In Android 3.0 and later, the thumbnail image is pointed to by
                    // PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI. In earlier versions, there is no direct pointer; instead,
                    // you generate the pointer from the contact's ID value and constants defined in
                    // android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts.
                    Utils.hasHoneycomb() ? Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI : Contacts._ID,

                    // The sort order column for the returned Cursor, used by the AlphabetIndexer
                    SORT_ORDER,



            };


            // The query column numbers which map to each value in the projection
            final static int ID = 0;
            final static int LOOKUP_KEY = 1;
            final static int DISPLAY_NAME = 2;
            final static int PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_DATA = 3;
            final static int SORT_KEY = 4;


        }
```

I do not past the whole code just part of the code.

Comment: Way too much code and too little info dude. Which line is causing the trouble? Also, your whole idea seems wrong, I can't imagine a scenario where you'd want to save something at the exact time a fragment gets created. It's not clear whether you're having problems with fragment api or database, those are two completely unrelated things -- you should separate them and clarify your question, otherwise noone will be able (or want to) help.

Comment: Acutally sir  First time I am using fragments in my code, so I dont have much idea how do I actually call the save data function , I actually I want to save my contact details to MYSQL database,so I can read and write data through php ,Please help me, yOU WANT TO know further please let me know but help me thanks

Comment: Well, fragments are a UI thing, the way you save your contacts shouldn't really depend on them. Determine at what time you want to save the contacts. If you need to do it as soon as possible, you're probably better off doing it in Application.onCreate(). But really, you seem to be lacking a good deal of general android knowledge, I suggest you read these two pages at least http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: In oncreateview when I called the save data function it give me a errors i.e inflating class fragments

Comment: Thanku sir, I am focusing on your suggestions,